# Installing flyway CLI gives command not found

Tags: command-line-interface, flyway

I try to run flyway repair on my server, but I have a problem installing the cli.
i extracted it on the server and i am at ~/flyway/flyway-4.2.0$ but it says command not found. Am I missing something? (Java is installed)

[Manual only says this](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/commandline)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running the command as `./flyway repair`

It appears you are on a linux server and it is necessary to run the command this way (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file). The Flyway docs are for a windows cmd prompt.

Comment: Great, it works. Also this link is very useful for me :)

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS as well. I was getting the error running `flyway migrate` but `./flyway migrate` worked. Thanks!